# String function in monetdb

Tags: postgresql, monetdb

Does Monetdb supports string function like `concat_ws` in Postgresql (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) ?

**Edit: Monetdb reference**

I look in the [Monetdb reference](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/Syntax) about supported operations, but nothing was related to String functions.

Comment: Did you find anything in the MonetDB manual?

Comment: I did not found anything, I'm still searching :)

Comment: Searching for string aggregate, string_agg, group_concat and so forth doesn't seem to yield anything interesting. So probably not. The better venue to ask this would be the MonetDB devs or a mailing list they maintain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went searching in the MonetDB `functions` table. The following list shows the set of supported string functions, with aliases omitted and with maximum parameters.

- ASCII: `SELECT ASCII('a');` → `97`
- CODE: `SELECT CODE(97);` → `a`
- CONCAT: `SELECT CONCAT('foo', 'bar');` → `foobar`
- INSERT: `SELECT INSERT('foXXXar', 2, 3, 'ob');` → `foobar`
- LEFT: `SELECT LEFT('foobar', 3);` → `foo`
- LENGTH: `SELECT LENGTH('foobar');` → `6`
- LOCATE: `SELECT LOCATE('bar', 'foobar', 0);` → `4`
- LOWER: `SELECT LOWER('FOOBAR');` → `foobar`
- LIKE: `SELECT 'foobar' LIKE 'foo%';` → `TRUE`
- LPAD: `SELECT LPAD('foo', 6, '_');` → `___foo`
- LTRIM: `SELECT LTRIM('___foo','_');` → `foo`
- REPEAT: `SELECT REPEAT('foo','3');` → `foofoofoo`
- RIGHT: `SELECT RIGHT('foobar', 3);` → `bar`
- RPAD: `SELECT RPAD('foo', 6, '_');` → `foo___`
- RTRIM: `SELECT RTRIM('foo___','_');` → `foo`
- SPACE: `SELECT SPACE(4);` →  (4 whitespace characters)
- SUBSTRING: `SELECT SUBSTRING('foobar', 2, 4);` → `ooba`
- TRIM: `SELECT TRIM('___foo___','_');` → `foo`
- UPPER: `SELECT UPPER('foobar');` → `FOOBAR`

Comment: do you mind telling me how did you find that ? thanks !

Comment: `select * from functions` and continue from there.